# iptables SNAT doesn't seem to work

Tags: iptables

I'm running `Debian Linux` behind a `Vyatta gateway`.
On my Debian I have the following `iptables`:

```
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -s 10.10.10.0/16 ! -d 10.10.10.0/16 -j SNAT --to-source 121.238.11.1-121.238.254 --persistent
```

But running `tshark`doesn't show any packets with ip address 121.238.11.1-121.238.254, only packets with source IP address from range 10.10.10.0/16.

What am I missing?

Comment: What is `--persistent`? I don't know this switch

Comment: Simply to make `iptables` persistent with `iptables-persistent`. But removing it doesn't change anything :(

Comment: The output of `iptables -nvL` and `iptables -t nat -nvL` would help.

Comment: There's only the one rule in my iptables. Everything else is handled by my Vyatta gateway for firewall rules.

Comment: But your debian machine is a router or something, isn't it? Or it at least forwards some packets?

Comment: Well, sort of. I have "client" with internal IPs trying to retrieve public internet packets. And therefor needs public IPs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you enabled ip forwarding on this NAT box?

```
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

And loaded the modules?

Specified the protocol?

```
-p tcp (if using tcp)
```

Comment: Which was it? It could help others in similar situations to show the functional rule. (You should also obfuscate external IP addresses)